# Как объединить части в grid UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

Пишу проект на UWP (C#), надо объединить ячейки в гриде. Как это сделать? (в нужных для объединения ячейках стоит буква G)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У элементов в сетки есть такие свойства, как `RowSpan` и `ColumnSpan`, вот ставьте там нужное значение, сколько элемент будет занимать соседних клеток.

Comment: спасибо, помогло